# Queue SUM of SQLite column - android

Tags: android, sqlite, sum

I have a listview populated from an SQLite database. I have several items that I successfully populate into the listview, however I'm having trouble with one last thing.

I'm trying to queue the sum total of the column `KEY_CONTENT6` which is a string type, however it only contains numbers. I'd like to keep it as a string, so to add it up I'm using `Double.valueOf()`. The problem is this code force closes on queue and I cant figure out whats wrong:

```
 public Cursor queueAll(){

  String[] columns = 
     new String[]{KEY_ID, "sum("+ Double.valueOf(KEY_CONTENT6) +")",
                  KEY_CONTENT9, KEY_CONTENT10 };

  Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns,

          null , null, KEY_CONTENT10, null, KEY_CONTENT9+ " DESC");


  return cursor;

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply use SUM, no need to use anything else..

```
String[] columns = 
     new String[]{KEY_ID, "sum(KEY_CONTENT6)",
                  KEY_CONTENT9, KEY_CONTENT10 };
```

It is valid for SQLite. Because, no matter what you set data type in SQLite, it stores values as string. So, type conversion is somewhat built-in in SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use java in a SQL statement, either stick to strait sql or iterate over the cursor and use java to do your calculation.

You can find everything there is to know about sqlite here http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is basically typeless, so you might be able to use `SUM` on your column even though it is a string. However, if it's meant to be a numeric column, why not give it a number type??